# htaccess rule for rewriting URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site like

```
http://www.mysite.com
```

When I click on sub menus of mysite it appears like

```
 http://www.mysite.com/services/my-service1
```

and a URL not found error is displaying. But I am getting the page when I give URL like

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.php?page=my-service1
```

But I need to show the page when I give URL like `http://www.mysite.com/services/my-service1`. How can we achieve this by writing the htaccess rule?

I tried this one, but not working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^services/([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: This should work fine. What is location of above .htaccess?

Comment: Its under public_html

Comment: Is services a sub directory under `public_html`? Are there other rules too? Are you sure .htaccess and mod_rewrite are enabled?

Comment: There isn't any sub folder. Yes htaccess and mod_rewrite are enabled. The problem is there is a services.html file under public_html. So when we make a request like http://www.mysite.com/services/my-service1 it is redirecting to http://www.mysite.com/services.html/my-service1. That is the issue here. How to solve this?

Comment: ok posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^services/([^/]+) index.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem is [`MultiViews`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html). Disable it by adding this line on top of your .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```